# preserving case for coldfusion structs when converted to JSON

Tags: coldfusion

Using the array notation for creating the keys in a struct used to preserve the case of the key.

```
<cfset var response = structNew()>
<cfset response[ "error" ] = 0>
<cfset response[ "message" ] = "">
<!--- this worked when converting this struct to a JSON
```

So when I actually put some data into the struct:

```
<cfset response.error = 1>
<cfset response.message = "There was an error inserting the record...">
```

I surprised when I saw this come across the firebug console:

`{"MESSAGE":"There was an error inserting the record...","ERROR":1}`

note, the information is what I was expecting to see.

I understand if I would have used `<cfset response.error = 0>`, for the case not to be preserved when converting it to a JSON, but this has worked for me in the past.  Am I doing something wrong that I'm blind to or did something change in CF10?

EDIT:

Before all of the responses came back, I tried what everyone said.

```
<cfset response["error"] = 1>
<cfset response["message"] = "There was an error inserting the record...">
```

and it worked. So, I'm guessing they changed how `serializeJSON` works in CF10.

Good to know.

Comment: Looks like this bug (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3322342) has been resolved in CF10 update 11 (http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-update-11.html). I haven't tested, just posting the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you continue to reference the struct key with bracket notation rather than dot notation, you should have no issue with case when using `serializeJSON()`.

After testing on CF9, however, it seems to work fine whether I use bracket- or dot-notation. This may be a difference between CF9 and 10 and, as Ray recommends, you may want to file a bug report for it.

Here's what I did in CF9:

```
<cfset response = structNew()>
<cfset response[ "error" ] = 0>
<cfset response[ "message" ] = "">
<!--- this worked when converting this struct to a JSON --->

<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(response)#</cfoutput><br /><br />

<!--- This outputs {"message":"","error":0} --->

<cfset response.error = 1>
<cfset response.message = "There was an error inserting the record...">

<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(response)#</cfoutput>
<!--- This outputs {"message":"There was an error inserting the record...","error":1} --->
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the expected behavior in CF9.  Once I switched it to array notation throughout, it worked fine.  I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: @RobM - Take a look at Ray's comment on his answer below. He is saying that it worked fine in CF10 for him. The only major difference I notice is that he is using `{}` to initialize the struct whereas you are using `structNew()`. I doubt that could be causing it, but you never know...

Comment: didn't work for me.. `<cfset var response = {}> {"MESSAGE":"There was an error inserting the record...","ERROR":1}`

Comment: @RobM I finally got around to testing on CF10 and the code listed above is working the same as it does in CF9. I'm not sure what's happening with your setup. :)

Comment: Everyone else seems to be able to get it to work like it supposed to, but for whatever reason, it doesn't for me.  I'm not sure what the problem is or what the difference in the setup is.  I'm just going use the bracket notation throughout.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem recently with CFSCRIPT and the {} notation while consuming a .net webservice that had case sensitive attribute names.  I needed to put quotes around my keys like follows: response = {"FirstName" = "Gerry", "LastName" = "Gurevich"}

Answer (score 3):

I believe if you continue to use bracket notation it will continue to work ok. A bit more typing I guess, but should work. If this is a change from CF9 though you may want to file a bug report.

Comment: As an FYI though, I tested with this in CF10 and it worked ok - kept the case: (oops, forgot Enter submitted): 

<cfset s = {}>
<cfset s["ray"] = 1>
<cfset s["cam"] = 2>
<cfset s.cam = 3>
<cfoutput>#serializejson(s)#</cfoutput>